# Why does date format changes to month first in date time object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, web

In a web application, I am passing datetime without formatting it in a XML response, just `item.Date` (`DateTime` datatype) is put in code.

No formatting is done. When I run the local server it returns the date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format and in live environment `DD/MM/YYYY`. Why this change is happening?

I checked on database collation and OS settings. Live environment had `English (Singapore)` in regional settings. However after changing local servers to `English (Singapore)` still live environment `DateTime` format is not being produced locally.

Collation:

```
In Live Environment - Latin1_General_CI_AI
In Local Servers    - SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

What could be the reason? how to resolve this rather than doing formatting in XML?

> **Update**

As suspected, Issue is with collation, regenerated the issue locally after creating DB with collation in live environment.

Comment: Please check the local date time is also the same as in your server

Comment: Can you please show how you represents these values? Can you show your work as well?

Comment: It's not clear where SQL Server comes into this - you've talked about embedding a `DateTime` value in XML... what does SQL have to do with that? And why don't you want to format the value in the XML? XML has a well-defined format for dates and times - why would you *not* want to use that? (Heck, if you use LINQ to XML you get that for free by setting an attribute or element value to a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`...)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and comments. 

@Prabhakantha Yes checked server date and local, its same format and same region settings.

Comment: @JonSkeet we are using LinQ to entities (Entity Framework)
We didnt format the XML document as XML is carrying sql queries (DML) and we are passing the date as DateTime object (may be wrong rationale) from the beginning.

Comment: It's very unclear where EF comes in here - you really need to provide more context in the question - but if you're trying to specify queries I would try to separate the parameter values from the SQL... at which point you *can* use the normal XML format for the values.

Answer (score 0):

Windows stores Date/Time settings per user. If IIS is running as LocalSystem, then you'll need to change the settings of the Default user:

In regedit, go here and set the appropriate values up for the locale and format that you want.

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International
```

That said, handling dates and times types under the assumption of any given format is A Really Bad Idea.

If you need date/time in a specific format for display, interop or whatever you should format the date time appropriately with one of the available [string formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Above registry shows the same regional settings which you find in Control Panel -> Region -> Formatting -> Date & Time Formats. Anyway thanks for comments & suggestion.